# HashMap по гласным

Tags: java

Запись в map слов из списка из файла, где ключ - количество гласных в слове, а значение - список слов, в которых присутствует получаенное количество гласных
Есть метод, который ищет согласные

```
public static int[] getCountVowelToOffer(String[] offers) {
    int[] result = new int[offers.length];
    String pattern = "[а, е, ё, и, о, у, ы, э, ю, я]";

    for (int i = 0; i < offers.length; i++) {
        result[i] = offers[i].length() - offers[i].toLowerCase().replaceAll(pattern, "").length();
    }
    return result;
}
```

помогите реализовать мапу

```
Map<Integer, List> findMap = new HashMap<>();
    int finalCount = count;
    Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file name"), Charset.defaultCharset())
            .stream().collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(word -> {
       int  number = finalCount;
        if (getCountVowelToOffer(array).equals(finalCount)) findMap.get(number).add(word);
        else {
            List<String> listResult= new ArrayList<>();
            listResult.add(word);
            findMap.put(number, listResult);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Легко сделать с помощью `Collectors.groupingBy`

```
// вообще й не гласная
static private final Pattern vowelPattern = Pattern.compile("[аеёийоуыэюя]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);

public static int countVowels(String s) {
    /*  java 8
    int count = 0;
    Matcher m = vowelPattern.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) count++;
    return count;
    */

    // java 9+
    return (int) vowelPattern.matcher(s).results().count();
}

public static Map<Integer, List<String>> getMap(String filename) throws IOException {
    return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename), Charset.defaultCharset())
            .stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> countVowels(s)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, так

```
public static Map<Integer, List<String>> getCountVowelMap(String ... offers) {
    final Set<Integer> vowels = "аеёийоуыэюя".chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    final Map<Integer, List<String>> findMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String offer : offers) {
        Integer countVowel = (int)offer.chars().filter(ch -> vowels.contains(ch)).count();
        if (findMap.containsKey(countVowel)) findMap.get(countVowel).add(offer);
        else {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(offer);
            findMap.put(countVowel, list);
        }
    }
    return findMap;
}
```